# How should I write the select query (SQL Server)

Tags: sql, sql-server

Table `Submits`:

```
* id : int(7)
* userID : varchar(30)
* questionID : int(7)
* score : int(7)
```

Table `users`:

```
* userID : varchar(30)
* name : varchar(40)
* password : varchar(100)
```

Table `question`:

```
* ID : int(7)
* name : varchar(20)
* link : varchar(100)
* enable : tinyint(1)
* successIterations : int(10)
* faildIterations : varchar(10)
* level : varchar(10)
* gameName : varchar(10)
* description : varchar(60)
```

I have this database as shown above which contains submits, users and question table.

I want to write a select statement that returns the userID and name from users table, score from submits table and name, level and gameName from question table, depending on the `questionID` which is known.

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well .. use

```
select u.userID, u.name, s.score, q.name, q.level, q.gameName
  from users u left join submits s on s.userID = u.userID
               left join questions q on q.ID = s.questionID
 where s.questionID = '<known value>'
```